# Swift reusable cell image being reused

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, deque

I am trying to have an image appear in certain cells of my UITableView only under certain conditions. When the conditions are met, the image appears as expected, but when I scroll down the list, the icon is seen in a cell towards the bottom, even though the condition was NOT met. I am gessing that this has something to the with the cell being a prototype and being reused in code, but cannot figure out how to fix. Here is the code I have:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("locCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

  var currentLoc = self.hereLocs[indexPath.row]
  var hereImage = UIImage(named: "loc")

  if currentLoc.currentlyHere! == true {
    cell.textLabel?.text = currentLoc.name!
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = currentLoc.vicinity!
    cell.imageView?.image = hereImage
  } else {
    cell.textLabel?.text = currentLoc.name!
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = currentLoc.vicinity!
  }

  return cell
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this in the else :

```
cell.imageView?.image = nil
```

Explanation:
UITableViews reuse cells. Because of this, you have to set the properties to account for both scenarios.

Comment: This is edited post! You can not copy from other's answer.

Comment: Oops! Sorry, I did see your response, but I did not take the time to read it. Please give the correct solution to @Ashish Kakkad as he was the first to post.

Comment: @Caleb No no, Don't worry brother. I have removed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you scroll the tableview then cellForRowAtIndexPath method call for the new upcoming cell and in this method you are using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier method for reusing cell then you will get a old cell. This cell can have the image if you had set on it previously. So you have to remove this image or set new one as your requirement. From your code you should remove the image using cell.imageView?.image = nil in the else block.